# Copy velocity of one object to other object

Tags: c#, unity, rigidbody

I have a script to pick up items with a VR controller. I connect the object to the VR controller through a `FixedJoint` on a rigidbody `attachPoint`. When I drop an item through destroying the Joint however it plummets straight down to the ground, no force from the controller is transferred to the released object. Thus I can't throw the object.

I tried it using the `AddForce()` method. `attachPoint`'s velocity is the controller's as it is a child of the controller. Relevant code below.

Can someone help me with transferring the velocity of the controller at the time of release to the object just released?

Thanks!

```
public class PickupCarryRelease : MonoBehaviour {

    public Rigidbody attachPoint;

    FixedJoint joint;
    GameObject obj;
    Collider grabbedObjColl;


    void Update()
    {
        Release();
    }

    void Release()
    {
        var device = SteamVR_Controller.Input((int)trackedObj.index);
        if (canGrab && joint != null && device.GetTouch(SteamVR_Controller.ButtonMask.Trigger))
        {
            var obj = joint.gameObject;
            var rb = obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

            grabbedObjColl.isTrigger = false;
            rb.detectCollisions = true;

            //Transfer velocity

            Destroy(joint);
            rb.AddForce(attachPoint.velocity, ForceMode.Impulse);
            StartCoroutine(GrabDelay());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is attachPoint.velocity, the velocity of your controller?

Comment: Yes it is, edited my question.

Comment: Add `Debug.Log(attachPoint.velocity); ` inside of that IF statement and ensure that velocity is actually valid.

Comment: @Jon Great suggestion, reports a velocity of (0.0, 0.0, 0.0). Am I right in assuming the rigidbody gets a velocity when it is a child of a moving object?

Comment: That would be your issue then.  That rigidbody is not reporting a proper velocity.  Looks like SteamVR_Controller.velocity is exposed.  I have never done VR as I cannot afford a setup for it.  Check out the source:  https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr/blob/master/unity_package/Assets/SteamVR/Scripts/SteamVR_Controller.cs

Comment: Now that probably invalidates my answer. I think I'll just outright delete it, however doing a direct velocity assignment might be something to look into.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 Thanks for the answer, that simple solution completely slipped my mind!

Comment: @Jon How would I go about determining it manually?

Comment: Try device.velocity.

Comment: Anytime.  Don't forget to buy my game :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will post this answer since this question was resolved by me in the comments above.

In order to get the velocity of the VR controller, you need to use:

```
var device = SteamVR_Controller.Input((int)trackedObj.index);
device.velocity;
```